# Using EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE to call a sub procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a function which has several sub-procedures inside it:

```
  create function func1 return varchar2
    v_string varchar2(100);
    proc1;
    proc2;
    proc3;        
  begin
    v_string := 'proc' || '1';   --- trying to make it simple
    execute immediate 'BEGIN '|| v_string ||'; END;';
    ...
```

Directly calling the sub-procedures does work; but I have dozens of sub-procedures - so I form a string variable with the 'proc' name and try to dynamically execute it in a loop.

When I do that I get an error - 'proc1' must be declared.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. The `proc1` etc. local procedures are out of scope and not visible in the dynamic SQL context.

You could potentially use a package to achieve a similar effect, but the procedures would have to be public (i.e. declared in the package specification).

This doesn't look like something you should be doing dynamically anyway though. If you want to decide which procedure to call at runtime, use a case statement with a different procedure call in each branch - something like [the example at the end of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35420034/266304).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Mr. Poole

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Mr. Poole  -  my issue is that there are dozens of sub-procedures I have to call dynamically based on rules and a rank assigned to those rules (which I read from a oracle table  -  and the rank can be changed on the fly by the business owner) - so I need a way to execute the procedures in a dynamic order if you will - it is rather unfortunate that Oracle does not allow me to execute a sub-procedure whose name is stored as a variable value...